# How to obtain probability distribution from the generating function $G(s) = e^{a(s-1)^2}$?

Tags: probability, derivatives, power-series, generating-functions

I was trying to get the probability distribution $p(n)$ from a generating function $G(s)$ like this:

$G(s) = e^{a(s-1)^2}=\sum s^np(n)$

I need first to do Maclaurin expansion of the exponential and then get the $n$th order term for $p(n)$.

My first thinking was it would be simple to calculate the derivatives. But it turns out to be much more difficult and also very interesting to generalize the $n$ order derivative.

I list a table for the powers and coefficients of each derivative order, finding that the powers are odd numbers for odd $n$, even numbers for even $n$, the coefficients are associated to $(n-1)$th order's powers and coefficients. It is easy to see the association but I cannot generalize it.

This calculation is also like $z$ transform but no existing result for it.

Anyone could give a shot and help me out?

Comment: check this out http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=nth+differential+of+e^%28x^2%29+

Comment: Try expanding the exponential and then the quadratic to get a double sum which (hopefully) simplifies.

Answer (score 1):

Using Maple and  the information given at
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_distribution

it is possible to obtain

[image]

The first ten probabilities are
[image]

These results can be obtained as follows.

The generating function for the Hermite polynomials is

$${{\rm e}^{2\,xt-{t}^{2}}}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {H_{{n}} \left( 
x \right) {t}^{n}}{n!}}$$

Then

$${{\rm e}^{-\alpha\, \left( 1-s \right) ^{2}}}={{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}{
{\rm e}^{2\,s\alpha-\alpha\,{s}^{2}}}
$$

making the change $$t=\sqrt {\alpha}s$$ we have

$${{\rm e}^{-\alpha\, \left( 1-s \right) ^{2}}}={{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}{
{\rm e}^{2\,t\sqrt {\alpha}-{t}^{2}}}
$$

and then we obtain

$${{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}{{\rm e}^{2\,t\sqrt {\alpha}-{t}^{2}}}={{\rm e}^{-
\alpha}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {H_{{n}} \left( \sqrt {\alpha}
 \right) {t}^{n}}{n!}}$$

it is to say

$${{\rm e}^{-\alpha\, \left( 1-s \right) ^{2}}}={{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}\sum 
_{n=0}^{\infty }{\frac {H_{{n}} \left( \sqrt {\alpha} \right)  \left( 
\sqrt {\alpha}s \right) ^{n}}{n!}}$$

Then we write

$$ \sum _{n=0}^{\infty }p_{{n}}{s}^{n}={{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}\sum _{n=0}^{
\infty }{\frac {H_{{n}} \left( \sqrt {\alpha} \right)  \left( \sqrt {
\alpha}s \right) ^{n}}{n!}}$$

Finally we obtain

$$p_{{n}}={\frac {{{\rm e}^{-\alpha}}H_{{n}} \left( \sqrt {\alpha}
 \right)  \left( \sqrt {\alpha} \right) ^{n}}{n!}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$G$, using your notation, is known in probability as the **probability generating function**. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function#Probabilities_and_expectations) for more details. It is seen on this link that 
$$p(k) = \dfrac{\left.G^{(k)}(s)\right|_{s=0}}{k!}$$
where $G^{(k)}$ denotes the $k$th derivative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that very well. When $G(s, t)=e^{a(s-1)t}$, the probability is Poisson distributed. But in my case $G(s)=e^{a(s-1)^2}$ which make things more complicated when calculating $G^{(k)}(s)$. I already expand it but have a very sophisticated form. Any suggestion for tackling this would be highly appreciated.